# Reduce password validation code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following code is the implementation of the authentication based on whether or not a user enters a password in the edit page of user data.

How could I simplify this code using only a few methods?

```
...

    $user = User::findOrFail($id); //Get role specified by id

    if($request->password === null){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=>'required|max:120',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id
        ]);
      $request->password = $user->password;
    }

    else{
      //Validate name, email and password fields          
      $this->validate($request, [
      'name'=>'required|max:120',
      'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
      'password'=>'required|min:6|confirmed'
      ]);
    }

    $input = $request->only(['name', 'email', 'password']); //Retreive the name, email and password fields
    $roles = $request['roles']; //Retreive all roles
    $user->fill($input)->save();

...
```

**Specs**

- Laravel ver.5.6

Comment: You allow empty password in your app?

Comment: You can just use one validation method with `$request->all()` and ignore `required` for password, that way you don't have to do the `else` part

Comment: I'm not allow empty password, that is required, but when user wants to edit user's data in the Edit Page then password field is can be entered or left blank.

Comment: You could use request validation. Which will clean up your controller a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'name'=>'required|max:120',
  'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
  'password'=>'nullable|required|min:6|confirmed'
]);
```

Use `nullable` rule in password validation. White saving the password use code like this:

```
if($request->password){
      $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
}
```

Comment: When after adjusted `nullable` but I couldn't login with my existed password. what is problem :(

Comment: Did you use the bulk update? like $user->update($request->all());

Comment: look at the modified one :)